How to view specific code lines/functions in which dpdk functions are getting executed using a backtrace when error has occurred during build
How can we view the code lines to know what specific part of code and the lines got executed to find out the error instead of the dpdk library functions mentioned here which are getting executed in the code and we cannot specifically determine where the error might have occurred as the codebase is huge
Given below is an example of a backtrace generated by the gdb compiler for an error which occurred during building of the project.
(gdb) bt
#0 0x00000000040135d7 in pci_uio_map_resource ( ) 
#1 0x000000000062c7ba in pci_plug.cold () 
#2 0x0000000004956abc in local_dev_probe ( ) 
#3 0x000000000496faea in _ handle_primary_request ( ) 
#4 0x0000000004974070 in eal_alarm_callback ( ) 
#5 0x00000000049767bc in eal_intr_thread_main () 
#6 0x00007f1a42e49ea5 in start_thread () from /lib64/libpthread.so.0 
#7 0x00007f1a3cc9bb0d in clone () from /lib64/libc.so.6

I expected the backtrace to show like this where the function name and files are mentioned but in case of dpdk it does not show like this, hence I want to know how can we view the above backtrace in a way similar to one given below



I expected the backtrace to show like this where the function name and files are mentioned but in case of dpdk it does not show like this

For file/line info, your dpdk must be compiled with debug info (usually the -g flag).
If you build dkpk yourself, add -g. If you have a pre-built library, you'll have to work with the provider of that library to get the build with debug info.
